# How to include caption for gallery using magnific popup?

Tags: css, gallery, magnific-popup

I am trying to include a caption on the actual webpage under the image while using the magnificence popup gallery. Using a div and class caption or carousel-caption, I am unable to do so without the images in the gallery stacking vertically one by one. How can I do this?

```
<a href="img/base/ggg.PNG" title="HELLO" class="chicken">
  <img src="img/base/pop.PNG" alt="remember your alt tag" />
</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.chicken').magnificPopup({ 
         type: 'image',
         gallery:{enabled:true}
         // other options here
         // end each line (except the last) with a comma
      });
   });
```

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sb4btox7/

Comment: you're going to have to post the code you have so far , the HTML , the CSS and if there is any relevant javascript.

Comment: you should also add a fiddle example .  Just because StackOverflow has a tag for magnific-popup still doesn't mean that 99% of javascript devs are going to have any idea what that it, and I ( and pretty much everyone else) aren't going to go and download it and read the docs just to get you an answer .

Comment: if you can, please provide screen or rough mockup of what exactly you need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since I don't yet have enough reputation points to comment, I'm commenting here, in addition to providing a solution.

Comment: JSFiddle isn't working with your http:// images because JSFiddle is trying to serve them from https://

Solution:

You are halfway there. There are 2 parts to making the captions work.

1. You correctly have put the link in the anchor tag and not the
   image tag
2. You must specify your title source in your
   initialization script like this.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.chicken').magnificPopup({ 
           type: 'image',
           gallery:{enabled:true},
           type: 'image',
           image: {
               titleSrc: 'title' 
               // this tells the script which attribute has your caption
           }
       });
   });
   ```

The script then automatically writes your caption to its div labeled `class="mfp-title"`

BONUS Solution: I needed my lightbox image to open in a new window for users on their phones to zoom in, so I added this after the first `titleSrc` declaration:

```
    titleSrc: 'title',
    titleSrc: function(item) {
        return '<a href="' + item.el.attr('href') + '">' + item.el.attr('title') + '</a>';
        }
```

This information is in the documentation: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html in the "Image Type" section

Comment: Thanks. Am I supposed to insert a div with class mfp-title somewhere? I am not using it currently.

Comment: The mfp-title div is only for the caption, so if you're not using a caption, you don't need the div. Otherwise, yes, you should place a div with this class where you want your caption to go.

Comment: Why is this code displaying one image per horizontal space so they are all stacked up vertically?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 6):

I tried to use the selected answer, but even using the documentation, the examples wouldn't work for me. What I ended up using was:

```
$('.elements').magnificPopup({
   type: 'image',
   gallery: {
       enabled: true
   },
   image: {
       titleSrc: function(item) {
          return item.el.find('img').attr('title');
       }
   }
});
```

This probably has something to do with the version I was using, but it wasn't clear what version the documentation was for. Hopefully this is useful to someone.